Mixing linear and nonparametric regression
What is the best approach when one has a regression problem, where one knows that the relationship between the dependent variable and some of the independent variables should be linear, while the relationship between the dependent variable and one or more other independent variables is nonlinear and of unknown form. For simplicity, assume the model is:
$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot x_1 + f(x_2) + \epsilon$
for unknown real numbers $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ and an unknown function $f$.
From the following question I gather that one approach is to iteratively find, in turns, $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ through linear regression, and $f$ through nonlinear regression. Or more generally to treat $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ as hyperparameters of the nonparametric regression problem of $f$, which can be optimised with any optimisation algorithm one desires, even random search.
Nonlinear regression model linear in some parameters
Is that the `standard' approach?

Terminology: For what is normally called nonlinear regression you need to know the form of $f$ (i.e. up to some finite set of unknown parameters). If you want the form of $f$ to remain unspecified (e.g. to just be some smooth function), that would be a special case of nonparametric regression; more specifically a special case of the additive model where one component is linear. In suitable packages this might be specified as something like y ~ x1 + s(x2) where s is some smooth function.

For example, see examples in gam in mgcv which use s(.) in this way.

@Glen_b Thanks, I wasn't aware of that distinction. It is indeed nonparametric regression which I mean. I will edit the title of my question to reflect this.

It seems like this would be straightforward to model with something like a generalized additive model (GAM), which allows you to estimate both linear and nonlinear associations in the same model. As a basic example using the mgcv package in R, one can fit the following model:
$$
y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + f(x_2) + \epsilon
$$
With a linear component and a spline in the same GAM:
#### Load Library and Data ####
library(mgcv)
dat <- gamSim(eg=1)

#### Fit Model ####
fit <- gam(
  y 
  ~ x0 # linear term
  + s(x1), # spline term
  data = dat
)

The s() here estimates a spline, while the term without this wrapper function is estimated in a way analogous to standard regression coefficients.

Nice answer Shawn (+1)

Thank you, I was hoping something like this might exist, but my search skills based on queries with "linear regression" and "nonlinear regression" were insufficient to surface it.

It can also be fitted as nonlinear least squares. With R, look at ?nls, which have an algorithm argument. Help page says algorithm  character string specifying the algorithm to use. The default algorithm is a Gauss-Newton algorithm. Other possible values are "plinear" for the Golub-Pereyra algorithm for partially linear least-squares models and "port" for the ‘nl2sol’ algorithm from the Port library – see the references. Can be abbreviated.

My first reaction when noticing the question at hnq was OP might be talking about GAM. +1.
